# Show that $\dim H^1(\Gamma(11)) = 3$

Tags: matrices, number-theory, group-homomorphism, group-cohomology

Let $\Gamma(11) \subset \text{SL}(\mathbb{Z})$ be the invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices with one of the entries $0 \pmod {11}$. A [congruence group](http://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/mf.bianchi.bianchicongruencesubgroup) is defined by:
$$ \Gamma(11) = \left\{ \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right): \left|\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right| = ad-bc = 1 \text{ and } 11 \big| c\right\} $$
The group cohomology can be thought of as the homomorphisms from $\Gamma(11) \to \mathbb{Z}$. In our case, $\dim H^1(\Gamma_{11}) = 3$ here is one element:
$$ \phi: \left( \begin{array}{cc} 7 & 5 \\ 11 & 8 \end{array}\right) \mapsto 1 \text{ and }
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 3 & 1 \\ 11 & 3 \end{array} \right) \mapsto -1 \text{ and }\left( \begin{array}{cc} 127 & 150 \\ 11 & 3 \end{array} \right) \mapsto 2$$
This might be the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ just the additive group on integers.  One obvious homomorphism from $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Z}^\times$ is $\det \mapsto \{ \pm 1\}$.  I am looking for a working defintion of first group cohomology.